# AmCharts with Angular 9: load csv data, chart is blank

Tags: angular, csv, amcharts

I'm using Angular 9 with AmCharts 4.

My need is to load CSV data into a Pie chart. Data looks like:

```
Operation Type, Quantity
Internal, 687
External, 456
```

Chart is declared as:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.chart = am4core.create(this.getChartID(), am4charts.PieChart);

    const subtitulo = this.chart.titles.create();
    subtitulo.text = this.subtitulo;
    subtitulo.fontSize = 10;

    const titulo = this.chart.titles.create();
    titulo.text = this.titulo;
    titulo.fontSize = 15;
    titulo.marginTop = 10;
}
```

This data comes from a servlet (yes, all CORS passed).
I can confirm that data *is* loaded (I can see "chart.data" values correctly), but the chart it self is not drawn after data load.

The code I'm using to load data is:

```
this.chart.dataSource.url = 'https://myserver.com/ng/DataService/?param1=342&param2=filterN&format=csv';

const csvParser = new am4core.CSVParser();
csvParser.options.useColumnNames = true;
this.chart.dataSource.parser = csvParser;
this.chart.dataSource.events.on('error', (error) => { console.log('Datasource error: ', error); });

this.chart.dataSource.load();
```

The chart is being created in
After "load" is executed, I can see in "Developer Tools" that data has been correctly loaded, but chart remains empty.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Where's your PieSeries object? Did you define one?

Comment: I really didn't defined one. As far as I could read in AmChart documentation, I assume chart would infer series from data. Complete examples are really missing at AmChart docs site.

Comment: No, it doesn't infer series from data,  you need to define one. There is an entire [section that explains how series objects work on the documentation site](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/series/) and [plenty of full pie chart examples](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/pie-chart/#Related_demos) on the Pie Chart documentation page.

Comment: Yes! Adding the series made it works. Thanks!!!

Comment: Would you please add your comment as a answer, because it really solved the problem! I would like to vote it up!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Defining the chart object and datasource URL isn't enough. Every chart type requires a [series object](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/series/) to be defined that defines further characteristics, including the fields to pull your data from.

```
var pieSeries = this.chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "Quantity";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "Operation Type";
```